# Table Function to Parse out array data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some trouble trying to split out the array string that I have stored in a SQL Table field "SQL Server 2014".

My data looks like

```
array(
                            "status"=>array("pre"=>"2","aft"=>1)
                            "tier_ppl"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>5.00)
                            "tier_commission"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>500.00)
                            "tier_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-14 08:54:32")
                            "affiliate_commission"=>array("pre"=>4.00,"aft"=>4.00)
                            "affiliate_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59")
                        )
```

And I need to make my out put look like :-

```
arrayname                      pre                           aft

status                         5.00                          5.00

tier_ppl                       5.00                          500.00

tier_commission                5.00                          500.00

tier_commission_datetime       2017-02-10 12:30:59           2017-02-14 08:54:32

affiliate_commission           4.00                          4.00

affiliate_commission_datetime  2017-02-10 12:30:59           2017-02-10 12:30:59
```

Each record that I have will have an array such as this though sometimes the pre or the aft will be blank.  I have tried going down the split function route but I am unable to make my data look the way I want it to, has anyone done something like this before that can help please.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to feed SQL Server data in this manner in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately the array data is already stored in this manner in the database/table and done by our overseas web development team, I have just been asked if there is a way to parse it out in the way I have described.

Comment: I would strongly advise that you tell them this is not a task that is suited to SQL Server and that they should really change their data import method.  You would also be sensible to explain where you want this data to go?  I am assuming that each array is a different table, given the different data types within the `for` and `aft` value sets?  What is your desired output in terms of tables and columns?  It would also help to see what a blank `pre` or `aft` value looks like.

Comment: I have already put forward the suggestion to break this data up in to relevant fields rather than just putting the array in to one field.  I need to be able to pass the id associated with the record that the array field is on and extract the values, there should be just one table e.g. OutputArray and the fields types can all be of type nvarchar.  An example of where there is no value for part of the affiliate_commission_datetime ("affiliate_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"","aft"=>"2017-02-14 08:16:30")  I should just be left with 3 columns arrayname, pre and aft as the column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is very, very, VERY much not the best way to do this.  Complex string manipulation is one of the worst things you can try to do in SQL Server.  Sort your dev team out before they tank your whole project with stupid design choices like the one in your question.

That aside, because I am bored at work I decided to show you just how stupid trying to do this is in SQL.  The below works for your example data, but could well fail on a host of `pre` and `aft` values.  For instance, if you had any of the `charindex` or `patindex` matching patterns in your data.

Utilising [Jeff Moden's string splitting function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) you can do the following:

```
declare @a nvarchar(1000) =
'array(
"status"=>array("pre"=>"2","aft"=>1)
"tier_ppl"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>5.00)
"tier_commission"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>500.00)
"tier_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-14 08:54:32")
"affiliate_commission"=>array("pre"=>4.00,"aft"=>4.00)
"affiliate_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59")
)';

select replace(left(s.Item,charindex('"=',s.Item,1)),'"','') as arrayname
    ,replace(replace(substring(s.Item,charindex('"pre"=>',s.Item,1),patindex('%,"%',s.Item) - charindex('"pre"=>',s.Item,1)),'"pre"=>',''),'"','') as Pre
    ,reverse(replace(replace(left(reverse(s.Item),charindex('>=',reverse(s.Item),1)-1),')',''),'"','')) as Aft
    ,s.Item
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@a,char(10)) s
where left(Item,1) = '"';
```

Which will output:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           arrayname           |         Pre         |         Aft          |                                                Item                                                |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| status                        | 2                   | 1                    | "status"=>array("pre"=>"2","aft"=>1)                                                               |
| tier_ppl                      | 5.00                | 5.00                 | "tier_ppl"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>5.00)                                                         |
| tier_commission               | 5.00                | 500.00               | "tier_commission"=>array("pre"=>5.00,"aft"=>500.00)                                                |
| tier_commission_datetime      | 2017-02-10 12:30:59 | 2017-02-14 08:54:32  | "tier_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-14 08:54:32")       |
| affiliate_commission          | 4.00                | 4.00                 | "affiliate_commission"=>array("pre"=>4.00,"aft"=>4.00)                                             |
| affiliate_commission_datetime | 2017-02-10 12:30:59 | 2017-02-10 12:30:59  | "affiliate_commission_datetime"=>array("pre"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59","aft"=>"2017-02-10 12:30:59")  |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi iamdave,  though this is a useful thing to know and gives me something to play with I have made it quite clear to our development team that this is not something that should be done at the back end and I completely agree with where you are coming from.  Thank you very much for the assistance with this, it has been much appreciated and something new to learn.